# Error with 'XML task' xslt to denormalise XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I am stuck with this error when trying to convert xml file using SSIS with a 'XML task' using xslt:

[Tâche XML] Erreur : « An error occurred with the following error message: "La feuille de style doit commencer par un élément 'xsl:stylesheet' ou 'xsl:transform' ou par un élément de résultat littéral qui a un attribut 'xsl:version', le préfixe 'xsl' identifiant l'espace de noms 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'.".

Here is the XLS file

```
   ***<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <RLUEx>
        <xsl:for-each select ="RLUEx">
           <RL0101Ax><xsl:value-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Ax"/></RL0101Ax>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </RLUEx>
     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>***
```

As you can see, it begins with xsl:stylesheet as requested in error message

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHsjX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoOpa.png)

Comment: Is it possible that you need to pass XSLT/XML file names properly to the SSIS XML Task? Please add a screen shot of it to your question.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, the XML and XSLT parameters should be switched.

Here is how SSIS XML Task, operation XSLT should be configured.

[image]

**XSLT**

You never shared the desired output. Here is my wild guess.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/RL">
        <RLUEx>
            <xsl:for-each select="RLUEx">
                <r>
                    <RL0101Ex>
                        <xsl:value-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Ex"/>
                    </RL0101Ex>
                    <RL0101Fx>
                        <xsl:value-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Fx"/>
                    </RL0101Fx>
                    <RL0101Gx>
                        <xsl:value-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Gx"/>
                    </RL0101Gx>
                </r>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RLUEx>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. But I have another problem: can't find the output of this operation: mmmm

Comment: @MoujahedHadj-Taieb, It is not clear what is behind the 'mmmm' file connection. You need to check where it is pointing to. Or just define a new file connection for the output file.

Comment: I found it, I mean 'mmmm.xml' but it is all empty. Would it help if I give u the xml input and the xls file

Comment: @MoujahedHadj-Taieb, Sure. Please provide (1) XML/XSLT pair, (2) Desired output, and (3) explain the logic.

Comment: Here  the link to XML/XLS pair.
https://github.com/mouj77/xmlt.
I  want to flatten the xml file: data in the RLUEx node. 
the next step is to do this for all the 1100 xml files in my repository before sending the result in a sql server table.

Comment: @MoujahedHadj-Taieb, I updated the answer. Overall, all ##1-3 should be in the original question, not outside. The #3 should be explicit XML based on the #1, not just wording about flattening.

Comment: great your xlt file made the dtsx work. I will try to go by my own the other data and I will certainly be back for the next step: loading the result for all the xml files in a sql server table. Thank you very much

Comment: @MoujahedHadj-Taieb, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.